# Postgres query to update a column with value of another

Tags: postgresql-performance

I have a query that is working: But, I'm not sure if it is the best.

```
update table1
set column1 = column2,
    column2 = 0
where id = 'X';
```

As you can see, I set the value of column2 to column1, and in the same query, I set column2 to zero.

Is that the best option to do this?

Comment: The update of the columns should conceptually happen at the same time. If that is your intention it should work just fine.

Comment: Note that it does not matter if you do col2=0, col1=col2. It will still work

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! You're missing an equals sign (`=`) between `id` and `'X'`, but apart from that, the query is fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this update, and it’s actually the preferred way to accomplish this type of update. With this method, you touch the table once instead of twice.

When setting a column to the value of another column, the value of column2 at the beginning of the update is the value applied to column1, even if you’re also updating column2 during the same update.